# How can I save the changes of my form on form close?

Tags: delphi, saving-data

I want to save the changes made to the properties of my components on android when closing the form. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to manually save them yourself, and then manually reload them on the next app start.

Comment: There's no built-in way to remember the complete state of your application. You will have to code this yourself. My preference is in a JSON file, but that's just me. There are surely other ways to do so, such as XML, INI, or perhaps even storing it on some REST server. It all depends on what your intentions are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people stated in the comments, this has to be done manually. For simple settings, it would be easy to use `inifiles`. For more advanced data saving you can use `json` or even `sqlite`.

Just a note. The `OnFormClose` event doesn't really work that well on android. I suggest that when you make changes, that's when you save them, or alternatively, provide something like a "save config" button.

Code example for saving ini on android:

```
procedure SaveSettingString(Section, Name, Value: string);
var
  ini: TIniFile;
begin
  ini := TIniFile.Create(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'config.ini');
  try
    ini.WriteString(Section, Name, Value);
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Example for loading a string:

```
function LoadSettingString(Section, Name, Value: string): string;
var
  ini: TIniFile;
begin
  ini := TIniFile.Create(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'config.ini');
  try
    Result := ini.ReadString(Section, Name, Value);
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When loading, what ever you set as the value, will be returned if that Name/Key does not exist.